# jQuery manual click option if scroll event fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, fadein

I am using the following code to show more content when the user scrolls to the bottom of the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#items').eq(0); 

    $("#items .itemDiv").slice(12).hide(); 
    var rowCount = $('#items .itemDiv').length; 

    $(window).scroll(function showMore (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

            $("#items .itemDiv:hidden").slice(0, 12).fadeIn("slow");

            if ($("#items .itemDiv:hidden").length == 0) {
                if (!('appendEnd' in showMore)) {
                    showMore.appendEnd = true;
                    $(".itemscrl").append("<div>You have reached the end.</div>");                  
                }
            }
        }
});
```

The problem is that it does not work on some devices (e.g. Android Chrome), so I would like to include the option of allowing the user to click an `<a>` element to trigger the function.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that when you call `e.preventDefault();` in your code you are breaking the scrollability of a page.

Remove the following from your code, I don't see any reason for disabling the default scrollability of a page:

```
e.preventDefault();
```